# Replacing Obsolete Closing Eventargs with new FormClosing args

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, user-controls, event-handling, formclosing

We are currently in the process of updating our database system and all of the files by building them(32bit-2005 VC#) to 64 bit now. Something I've come across is the leaking of data when an assignment using **this.closing += new CancelEventArgs(Event Name);** I've found it to be obsolete as fellow colleagues have put it and am looking for a way to switch to using the FormClosing event.

...

**Old Code and Event Ex.**

```
this.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(AssignUsers_Closing);


private void AssignUsers_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        "some event"

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowException se = new ShowException();
        se.ShowDialog(ex);
    }
}
```

This is where I'd like to convert to the FormClosing Event so that windows can take care of the data leak for me rather than having to add a -= statement for each event like this to the .dispose() function.

**Idea/New Code**

```
private void AssignUserForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        *code*
        // Use e.cancel to test whether to close the form or not.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowException se = new ShowException();
        se.ShowDialog(ex);
    }
}
```

Would this be a viable alternative. Any suggestions on how to make this change?

**EDIT: BETTER OVERVIEW OF MY QUESTION**

Changing this:

```
public AssignUserForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitMe();

            try
            {
                Database.ApplyFieldSecurity(this);
            }

            catch { }
        }

        private void InitMe()
        {
            try
            {
                this.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(AssignUsers_Closing);

                // Get the users from the system


               //Binding happens

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Turning it into something where I can use Windows Events to simply create a FormClosing event.

Comment: Why do you think you have a memory leak here?  Have you run tests or have any reference material?  My understanding is that since your event handlers are all inside the form, the GC will still destroy everything (assuming there are no **outside** references to the form).

Comment: There are many outside references. This happens to be a dialog form that comes up that lets us assign a user to our XTTMLProcessing unit. This is the simplest I could find because there is no code inside of the try statement. A data leak is occurring because this event is created whenever a user/employee hits the button that cancels this form. It is never disposed of. Otherwise I may not be understanding what you mean.

Comment: There are some misconceptions here.  First of all, FormClosing just a replacement for Closing.  It's almost the same. You shouldn't have to change your code much at all.  Just change this.Closing += ... with this.FormClosing += and fix the compile errors.  Next misconception, I don't see any "data leak" here and you rarely need to -= an event handler.  I certainly don't see a need to do so here.  Can you clarify any of these points?  I'm just not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: The problems were solved. There was a data leak occurring between our database and when the control that this dialog belonged to were loading. I appreciate all of the help. The database shot over the information before the dialog loaded, and then would send it over again. Only one set of the data was properly disposed of. We fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems were solved. There was a data leak occurring between our database and when the control that this dialog belonged to were loading. I appreciate all of the help. The database shot over the information before the dialog loaded, and then would send it over again. Only one set of the data was properly disposed of. We fixed the problem. Thank you. –